# Type 'Observable<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>

Tags: angular

I am upgrading angular  application to angular 8 and getting the following error
What I have changed is to make the promise pipeable

```
     Type 'Observable<unknown>' is missing the following properties
    from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]
return this.http.post(this._checkExecuteTradeUrl, requestBody, this.getRequestHeaders())
       .pipe(toPromise());
```

My current code is

```
import { map, tap, toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';

public CheckExecuteTrade(model: TradeNotification): Promise<any> {

        const header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

        const requestBody = JSON.stringify(model);
        return this.http.post(this._checkExecuteTradeUrl, requestBody, this.getRequestHeaders())
            .pipe(toPromise());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toPromise()` is not a pipeable operator according the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) because it:

> is not a pipable operator, as it does not return an observable

Move the `toPromise()` to outside the `pipe()`:

```
return this.http.post(this._checkExecuteTradeUrl, requestBody, this.getRequestHeaders())
  .toPromise();
```

If you need to execute other pipeable operators you can still use them inside `pipe()`, but `toPromise()` cannot be added there.

```
return this.http.post(this._checkExecuteTradeUrl, requestBody, this.getRequestHeaders())
  .pipe(map(r => r.toLowerCase(), tap(r => console.log(r))
  .toPromise();
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: If i do that the above error goes but i get error module has no exported member 'toPromise' for line import { map, tap, toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: You would not import `toPromise()` from `rxjs/operators` as it's not exported from `rxjs/operators`, remove it from there. You can just use `toPromise()` on any `Observable`.